# use_ssl value changed, but session already started when trying to make https request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, request, net-http

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 and this code for making a Net::Http get request

```
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    if !headers.nil?
      headers.each do |k, v|
        req[k] = v
      end
    end
    res = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start do |http|
      http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == "https")
      http.request(req)
    end
    status = res.code
    content_type = res['content-type']
    content_encoding = res['content-encoding']
    content = res.body
```

However, when I make one in which the scheme is “https”, I get the following error

```
Error during processing: use_ssl value changed, but session already started
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:758:in `use_ssl='
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:118:in `block in get_content'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
```

How do I set https while still being able to make my GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs, [`use_ssl`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP/use_ssl%3D)
must be set before starting session.

This is my usual flow:

```
uri          = URI 'some endpoint with encoded params'
http         = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
headers      = headers.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v }
http.get(uri.request_uri, initheader = headers)
```

See the docs on [`get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP/get).

---

Sidenote on your

```
if !headers.nil?
```

It would be more readable if you just check for presence:

```
if headers.present?
```

Or even shorter:

```
if headers # would return true unless it's nil or false
```

Comment: Thanks but where do you add the headers to your request?